# The Lambda ARN (Amazon Resource Name) does not show up at top right when i create a function for Alexa skill set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I started playing around with Alexa skill set, I followed the steps as mentioned on the amazon development document and created a lambda function for Event source "Alexa skill set". ARN did not show up at top right as mentioned in the doc.

I tried manually as below

```
arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name

arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:talkToBerna
```

but no luck... error: The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.

Can someone put me in right direction? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

An Amazon Resource Name (ARN) is a file naming convention used to identify a particular resource in AWS and they uniquely identify AWS resources.

If you successfully created a Lambda function (Independently if it is triggered by *Alexa Skills Kit* or not) you will get an ARN. You will see it in the top right corner of the screen, just like this:

[image]

Comment: If I have a working ARN endpoint, should I not be able to see it under the Lambda console?  I am not seeing it, but my Alexa skill is working.  Thank you.